# question is duplicate of what, precisely?

Tags: support

Stop marking questions as duplicates without linking to the duplicate in question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/60651/how-can-i-remove-unity-safely

Yes, I'm sure that this is a duplicate question/request.  To bring this full circle, please mark it as such and be sure not to link to what it's a duplicate of.

Comment: There appears to be a link right on the question.

Comment: right you are, I was looking at "closed as exact duplicate by htorque, Javier Rivera, Jorge Castro, fossfreedom♦, Stefano Palazzo♦ Sep 9 '11 at 15:15" and not seeing it.

Comment: I just like the meta-meta that this question is a duplicate.  Clearly there needs to be another level of meta just to discuss this in full.